# Laravel 5.6 - Backup mySql database to S3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to backup an entire mysql database to S3 like this:

```php
<?php
    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

    class DatabaseBackup extends Command {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'backup:database';
        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Take a backup of the entire DB and upload to S3.';
        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d_h-i');
            $user = env('DB_USERNAME');
            $password = env('DB_PASSWORD');
            $database = env('DB_DATABASE');
            $command = "mysqldump --user={$user} -p{$password} {$database} > {$date}.sql";
            $process = new Process($command);
            $process->start();
            while ($process->isRunning()) {
                $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
                $s3->put('gallery-app-db/' . $date . ".sql", file_get_contents("{$date}.sql"));
                unlink("{$date}.sql");
            }
        }
    }
```

But when running `php artisan backup:database` and then looking at the bucket .sql file, and downloading the .sql file locally, it shows like this instead of the actual database/tables being in the file:

[image]

Any idea how to have the .sql dump actually work and backup the real database along with all its tables instead of the usage file?

Comment: should be `if ($process->isSuccessful()) {` ...s3 put etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your password contains a character that ends a shell command, like `;` `&` `|` `&&` `||`

Or a character that ends a command-line argument, like whitespace.

Or some other special characters like any type of quotes, or `$` or `!`.

Without quoting the password, it's likely to generate a truncated command.

I suggest putting your username and password in an options file and then reference that options file with `--defaults-file=...`

```
$command = "mysqldump --defaults-file=mysql-dump.cfg {$database} > {$date}.sql";
```

The mysql-dump.cfg should contain something like:

```
[client]
user = <your user>
password = <your password>
```

That will also be nice to avoid putting your password in plain view from anyone who can run `ps`.